# Solve this limit: $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^{-it\sqrt{x}}}{(1-\frac{it}{\sqrt{x}})^x}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

i was trying to solve this limit: $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^{-it\sqrt{x}}}{(1-\frac{it}{\sqrt{x}})^x}$

I have tried to use the fact that $\lim_{x\to\infty} (1+1/x)^x =e$.

$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^{-it\sqrt{x}}}{(1-\frac{it}{\sqrt{x}})^x} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^{-it\sqrt{x}}}{((1-\frac{it}{\sqrt{x}})^\sqrt{x})^\sqrt{x}} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^{-it\sqrt{x}}}{e^{-it\sqrt{x}}}=1 $

I am doing something wrong, probably abusing the fact that $\lim_{x\to\infty} (1-it/\sqrt{x})^\sqrt{x}=e^{-it}$ in this situation.

The limit shoud be $e^{-t^2/2}$, but how can i prove it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

$$\left(1-\frac{it}{\sqrt x}\right)^{-x}=e^{-x\log\left(1-\frac{it}{\sqrt x}\right)}=e^{x\left(\frac{it}{\sqrt x}+\frac12 \left(\frac{it}{\sqrt x}\right)^2+O\left(\frac{it}{\sqrt x}\right)^3\right)}$$

Comment: Thank you! I thought that the Taylor series would have been useful, but did not know how to use them

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  -Mark

Comment: And feel free to up vote and best vote as you see fit of course.  ;-))